# Date Changing Due to Timezone Setting

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

The date I store in mysql looks fine when viewing the database, but when I am viewing the date it is always behind a day.

The mysql data type is "date".
I am getting the date column from mysql using UNIX_TIMESTAMP.
I am displaying the date using php's date() function.
I am using bluehost and configured php.ini to use Los Angeles time zone.

Example: I create a new article and key in 2013-05-08. It gets stored as a date type in mysql showing 2013-05-18. But when I go to view it later it shows 2013-05-07.

The timestamp is 1367992800, which is Wed, 08 May 2013 06:00:00 GMT in GMT, but in my timezone Tuesday, May 07, 2013 11:00:00 PM.

How do I display the originally intended date of 2013-05-18? I do not want to change my timezone to another since Los Angeles is my correct time zone and for all my other methods where we need to record a timestamp, it is accurate.

Comment: Your issue is the wrong timestamp is being inserted into the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your date to be independent on timezone you should store it in a column that does not transform the value. So the `date` column type you've chosen is quite appropriate.

The problem comes when you try get that date in UNIX TIMESTAMP. UNIX TIMESTAMP is an amount of seconds since 01.01.1970 in GMT. It means that mysql converts your date into timestamp in GMT using it's timezone settings.

PHP date function also depends on php timezone settings and converts timestamp into date in the current timezone.

To get date from MySQL without converting it into current timezone just do not fetch it using UNIX_TIEMSTAMP function. Get it as is or using DATE_FORMAT function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime object.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$date->setTimezone($timezone);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I picked another answer, but I did learn something from your answer which I am going to apply to another part of my code.